# How do i parse json with web client and display it in the console?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();

string value = client.DownloadString("http://www.onemap.sg/publictransportation/service1.svc/routesolns?token=qo/s2TnSUmfLz+32CvLC4RMVkzEFYjxqyti1KhByvEacEdMWBpCuSSQ+IFRT84QjGPBCuz/cBom8PfSm3GjEsGc8PkdEEOEr&sl=39167.4524,35518.8625&el=28987.5163,33530.5653&startstop=&endstop=&walkdist=300&mode=bus&routeopt=cheapest&retgeo=true&maxsolns=1&callback=");

 // Write values.
 Console.WriteLine("Results:");
 Console.WriteLine(value.Length);
 Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Error message shows:
'System.Net.WebClient' does not contain a definition for 'DownloadString' and no extension method 'DownloadString' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.WebClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In windows phone you're forced in most cases to program in an asynchronous way.
So instead of DownloadString, you have to use DownloadStringAsync as shown here in this sample:

```
  var client = new WebClient();

  client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(loadHTMLCallback);
  client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.myurl.com/myFile.txt"));
//...

public void loadHTMLCallback(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  var textData = (string)e.Result;
  // Do cool stuff with result
  Debug.WriteLine(textData);
}
```

Source:
http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Asynchronous_Programming_For_Windows_Phone_8

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> //Initialize new Client
> HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
> ```

```
//Response will handle the returned JSON
HttpResponseMessage response;

//URI of the service
string strURI = "http://www.onemap.sg/publictransportation/service1.svc/routesolns?token=qo/s2TnSUmfLz+32CvLC4RMVkzEFYjxqyti1KhByvEacEdMWBpCuSSQ+IFRT84QjGPBCuz/cBom8PfSm3GjEsGc8PkdEEOEr&sl=39167.4524,35518.8625&el=28987.5163,33530.5653&startstop=&endstop=&walkdist=300&mode=bus&routeopt=cheapest&retgeo=true&maxsolns=1&callback=";

//String that the response will be converted to.
string strResponseJSONContent = "";

//Lets the client know to expect JSON
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

//Getting the JSON and saving it to response
response = client.GetAsync(strURI).Result;

//Setting response to a string
strResponseJSONContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

You will need to add `using System.Net.Http` and `using System.Net.Http.Headers`

I haven't tested this in your specific scenario or with your service but I can't see why it wont work for you as it gets the JSON asynchronously.